# SSHFS mounts on a mobile laptop - system hangs when not on LAN

Tags: mount, fstab, sshfs

This is an Arch Linux system. I have 7 SSHFS mounts listed in /etc/fstab. They all use these options:

```
<source> <mountpoint> fuse.sshfs x-systemd.automount,_netdev,user,follow_symlinks,identityfile=/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa,default_permissions
```

The source for these mounts is a local file server. When connected to the LAN, everything works as expected.

However, when the laptop is elsewhere, these mounts cause a problem. Booting up takes a long time and some applications will hang for a long time. For example, Dolphin opens and hangs, then has to be force closed.

I would like for these SSHFS mounts to only be attempted when the laptop is connected to the LAN via wired Ethernet.

How can this be achieved?

(I could be wrong, but I don't believe autofs is the solution because I don't want the mounts to be attempted upon browsing to a mountpoint (as in Dolphin), unless the system is connected to the LAN.)

Comment: Did you have a look at creating a [udev rule](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev)

Comment: @RubberStamp - udev seems like a good idea. I would need some help to implement it in this case. I wasn't even aware that udev could be used in this way until you suggested it.